# Checking out orphan branch in new work-tree

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-worktree

I know that a new orphan branch can be created like so:

```
git checkout --orphan <new_branch>
```

however this uses my current work tree which I want to leave completely untouched. I tried:

```
git --work-tree=/tmp/test checkout --orphan <new_branch>
```

but this also seem to use my current work tree and not the one I specified using `--work-tree`.

I could use a second clone, but that does not seem optimal. Any way of solving this using work-trees?

Answer (score 14):

Make a worktree with detached head then orphan it:

```
git worktree add --detach /.../dir
cd /.../dir
git checkout --orphan branch
```

Comment: `d=subdir; n=some-branch; git worktree add --detach --no-checkout $d; git -C $d checkout --orphan $n; git -C $d reset; git -C $d clean -fdq; echo hello >$d/test.txt; git -C $d add test.txt; git -C $d commit -m init`

Answer (score 3):

You can try [git-worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree).

```
git checkout --orphan <new_branch>
git commit
git worktree add /tmp/test <new_branch>

# switch to the previous branch
git checkout -
# or
git checkout <previous_branch>

cd /tmp/test
# do something to <new_branch>
```

Now `/tmp/test` is a sub worktree. It shares the same `.git` with the main worktree. If you don't need the sub worktree any more, you can simply remove `/tmp/test`. The new commits are stored in the main repository.

If your Git does not support git-worktree yet, you need a newer version.

Comment: I actually ended up with something similar here now when investigating. Just that  I created the worktree first, and then did the orphan checkout there. Then I avoid switching branch in the main work tree.

Answer (score 2):

With Git 2.42 (Q3 2023), '[`git worktree add`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4dd046932835d14c449f04ee0f3885669cad60c5/Documentation/git-worktree.txt#L66)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree#Documentation/git-worktree.txt-addltpathgtltcommit-ishgt))</sup> learned how to create a worktree based on an orphaned branch with `--orphan`.

So this should be supported.

See [commit 926c40d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/926c40d04b5a77e00d3b22a5d2696c22b81569cc), [commit 128e549](https://github.com/git/git/commit/128e5496b325640f0a09cc1d5b1e346c069b410f), [commit 35f0383](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35f0383ca61db8f0b6ee1e9002150bbb13649993), [commit 7ab8918](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7ab891898524abbeb2c52f3f55fcf5e2457f930b), [commit 9ccdace](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ccdace1e83d22f0f618926e97b659e503b5fd94), [commit ed6db0e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed6db0e9fff14590f501eba24f91be1867e5e346), [commit 1b28fbd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b28fbd218cbefc9e5aa8c23d241b7cc8ee85878), [commit b71f919](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b71f919dda784fdf90901f1a2d848ccd22a49eb0) (17 May 2023) by [Jacob Abel (`0xnu11pwn`)](https://github.com/0xnu11pwn).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4dd0469](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4dd046932835d14c449f04ee0f3885669cad60c5), 22 Jun 2023)</sup>

> ### [`worktree add`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35f0383ca61db8f0b6ee1e9002150bbb13649993): introduce "try `--orphan`" hint
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jacob Abel</sup>

> Add a new advice/hint in [`git worktree add`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/35f0383ca61db8f0b6ee1e9002150bbb13649993/Documentation/git-worktree.txt#L66)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree#Documentation/git-worktree.txt-addltpathgtltcommit-ishgt))</sup> for when the user tries to create a new worktree from a reference that doesn't exist.
>
> Current Behavior:
>
> ```bash
> % git init foo
> Initialized empty Git repository in /path/to/foo/
> % touch file
> % git -C foo commit -q -a -m "test commit"
> % git -C foo switch --orphan norefbranch
> % git -C foo worktree add newbranch/
> Preparing worktree (new branch 'newbranch')
> fatal: invalid reference: HEAD
> %
> ```
>
> New Behavior:
>
> ```bash
> % git init --bare foo
> Initialized empty Git repository in /path/to/foo/
> % touch file
> % git -C foo commit -q -a -m "test commit"
> % git -C foo switch --orphan norefbranch
> % git -C foo worktree add newbranch/
> Preparing worktree (new branch 'newbranch')
> hint: If you meant to create a worktree containing a new orphan branch
> hint: (branch with no commits) for this repository, you can do so
> hint: using the --orphan option:
> hint:
> hint:   git worktree add --orphan newbranch/
> hint:
> hint: Disable this message with "git config advice.worktreeAddOrphan false"
> fatal: invalid reference: HEAD
> % git -C foo worktree add -b newbranch2 new_wt/
> Preparing worktree (new branch 'newbranch')
> hint: If you meant to create a worktree containing a new orphan branch
> hint: (branch with no commits) for this repository, you can do so
> hint: using the --orphan option:
> hint:
> hint:   git worktree add --orphan -b newbranch2 new_wt/
> hint:
> hint: Disable this message with "git config advice.worktreeAddOrphan false"
> fatal: invalid reference: HEAD
> %
> ```

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/35f0383ca61db8f0b6ee1e9002150bbb13649993/Documentation/config/advice.txt#L141-L144):

> ### `worktreeAddOrphan`
>
> Advice shown when a user tries to create a worktree from an
> invalid reference, to instruct how to create a new orphan
> branch instead.