# Using git log on a bare git repository with remote name in revision

Tags: git, git-remote, git-log, git-bare, git-worktree

I've been experimenting with `git worktree` and found some weird issue. Maybe it has to do cloning the repository as `--bare`.

```
$ cd ~
$ git clone --bare https://github.com/actions/checkout.git
```

The checkout repository has a remote called `origin`:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/actions/checkout.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/actions/checkout.git (push)
```

In upstream projects I usually have multiple remotes and I like to look at the logs of each remote by doing `git log origin/main` for example.

Let's do that in the bare repository:

```
$ cd ~/checkout.git
$ git log origin/main
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/main': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Why is that?

Even when I create a worktree for a hotfix I get the same error:

```
$ cd ~/checkout.git
$ git worktree add -b hotfix ~/checkout.git/hotfix main
$ cd ~/checkout.git/hotfix
$ git log origin/main
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/main': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Adding the `--` separator from the help also doesn't help:

```
$ git log origin/main --
fatal: bad revision 'origin/main'
```

Comment: What does `git branch --all` say?

Comment: From the docs on `bare`: "This obviously implies the --no-checkout because there is nowhere to check out the working tree. Also the branch heads at the remote are copied directly to corresponding local branch heads, _without mapping them to refs/remotes/origin/._ When this option is used, _neither remote-tracking branches_ nor the related configuration variables are created." My italics. QED.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @matt for you comments. They were helpful.

I don't know if this is the way one is supposed to be using worktrees but if I want to create a worktree for a hotfix based on `origin/main` and use the really remote branch notation `origin/main` I can do it like this.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/actions/checkout.git
$ cd checkout
$ git worktree add -b hotfix ../checkout-hotfix origin/main
$ git worktree list 
$ git worktree list
/home/kwk/checkout         72f2cec [main]
/home/kwk/checkout-hotfix  72f2cec [hotfix]
```

This is solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this (at least not in any obvious way):

1. Clone a bare repository
2. Use multiple remotes

Because (as [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77066277/using-git-log-on-a-bare-git-repository-with-remote-name-in-revision#comment135859537_77066277) explained) a bare repository doesn't have remotes. So
there isn't a way to reference different remote-tracking branches.

(As a side-note though you *can* have (1). Using worktrees with a bare
repository works fine. But you can't both of these.)

You don't explain why you want a bare repository. I'll just assume that
you don't want to [waste disk space](https://lore.kernel.org/git/CAPMMpog3o=DtOrC9L6ED42XkegdObkh3rGm617q4u2oofBC1TA@mail.gmail.com/T/#m8eb3902720e3de67cd002a5e6f61dc8ee187275b) on using a worktree in a
directory which contains the repository when you won't be using it.

First of all you will need a non-bare repository. But the working for that
repository (for the main worktree) doesn't need to take up any space. You
can do that by creating a branch which has an [empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76067970/1725151):

```
git clone <name>
cd <name>
# Use a branch name that you won't need
git switch --orphan unborn-in-the-usa
git clean --force -xd
git commit --allow-empty --message=Init
# Add more remotes
git remote add <name2>
git remote add <name3>
# Start making worktrees
git worktree add -b hotfix ~/checkout.git/hotfix main
```

This setup will only use a tiny amount of more disk space compare to a
bare repository since the main worktree will have an empty worktree.